# What is fastest for nightly Windows7 local drive to USB external drive backup: ROBOCOPY, XCOPY, or BeyondCompare?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup, robocopy, beyondcompare

I have a batch file that backs up all my work every night.
It copies my internal C: an SSD to my primary external USB-3.0 hard disk, and also that primary external hard disk to a secondary external hard disk.

I've been using ROBOCOPY for years.

But, is XCOPY or BeyondCompare faster?

Comment: I have not used xcopy but robocopy's speed can be affected by the switch that you use.  You can use the /MT switch and multi-thread which would allow you to use more than the default 8 threads (faster copy time)

Comment: Might this depend on the job?

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia ROBOCOPY:  "Robocopy functionally replaces Xcopy, with more options...Robocopy is noted for capabilities above and beyond the built-in Windows copy and xcopy commands, including the following:"  ESPECIALLY:  "Multithreaded copying"

Comment: This is interesting information, but it doesn't answer the question of which is fastest.